# Complicated symbolic coefficient slows down equation solving

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, algebraic-manipulation

Here's a simple example for `Solve`:

```
test[f_] :=
 ListPlot[Table[{n, 
    First@AbsoluteTiming@With[{c = Nest[f, c, n]}, Solve[c x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x]]}, 
       {n, 0, 100, 5}], Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All]

test[Sqrt[c + #] &]
```

[image]

For any value of `n`, `Solve` is essentially dealing with the same equation, but the timing increases signifiantly as the coefficient `c` becomes more compilcated. Similar behavior can be observed in the tests for `DSolve` and `RSolve`. (I believe there're more.)

This truth astonishes me, because I thought *Mathematica* is clever enough to handle this sort of thing <strike>so I decide to write this post for complaining</strike>. To make this post a question, I want to ask:

1. Why *Mathematica* is cheated by the complicated coefficient?
2. Is there any general method to circumvent the issue? In my simple example, we just need to replace to only complicated coefficient with a simple one, but the coefficient to be replaced is not always obvious.

Comment: Maybe something like my [``ConstantsGrouping` `` package](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103937/14303) would be useful here?

Comment: @jkuczm That sounds like an answer to me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know why *Mathematica* is slowed down by complicated constant, maybe there's a simple way to avoid it, but until someone finds this simple way you could use my [`` ConstantsGrouping` `` package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103937/14303).

It provides `GroupConstants` function that can replace combinations of arbitrary complicated constant expressions with auto-generated "simple" constants. It returns pair containing "simplified" expression and `Association` of new constants to old constants combinations:

```
eq = Nest[Sqrt[c + #] &, c, 5] x^2 + x + 1 == 0
GroupConstants[eq, x]
(* 1 + x + Sqrt[c + Sqrt[c + Sqrt[c + Sqrt[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[c] + c]]]] x^2 == 0 *)
(* {
       1 + x + x^2 C[1] == 0,
       <|C[1] -> Sqrt[c + Sqrt[c + Sqrt[c + Sqrt[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[c] + c]]]]|>
} *)
```

One can solve "simplified" equation, then replace "simple" constants with original combinations of constants to get the same result as solving original equation:

```
Solve[eq, x] ===
    With[{eqConstsPair = GroupConstants[eq, x]},
        Solve[First@eqConstsPair, x] /. Last@eqConstsPair
    ]
(* True *)
```

`Solve` timings with and without `GroupConstants`:

```
ListPlot[
    With[{f = Sqrt[c + #] &},
        Table[
            {
                n, 
                With[{c = Nest[f, c, n]}, 
                    First@AbsoluteTiming@Solve[c x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x]
                ]
            },
            {n, 0, 100, 5}]
    ],
    Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All
]

ListPlot[
    With[{f = Sqrt[c + #] &}, 
        Table[
            {
                n,
                With[{c = Nest[f, c, n]},
                    First@AbsoluteTiming@With[
                        {eqConstsPair = GroupConstants[c x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x]},
                        Solve[First@eqConstsPair, x] /. Last@eqConstsPair
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {n, 0, 100, 5}
        ]
    ],
    Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: Timing plots]

Comment: I really like this answer, and I really like your package as well! Have you considered adding it to the listings at [PackageData.net](http://packagedata.net)? (+1 of course)

Comment: @MarcoB [Done](http://packagedata.net/index.php/#package-206). Currently it just links to M.SE answer which, I guess, is not very convenient. When I find some time I'll move it to GitHub.