# How does one check a function monotonicity?

Tags: functions

[image]
the question is to analyze $f(x)$ for monotonicity. I know I need to use `D[f[x], x]` and check if it is less than or greater to zero, but `NSolve` is not working properly.

```
f[x_] := 
  Sqrt[1 - a + (b + c) (c + b x + c x) - 
    Sqrt[(b + 2 c + a c)^2 - (b^2 - c^2)(3 + 4 a - a^2 + b^2 - c^2) x + 
      (b^2 - c^2) x^2]] + 
  Sqrt[1 - a + (b + c) (c + b x + c x) + 
    Sqrt[(b + 2 c + a c)^2 - (b^2 - c^2) (3 + 4 a - a^2 + b^2 - c^2) x + 
     (b^2 - c^2) x^2]] + 
  Sqrt[1 + a - (b - c) (c - b x - c x) - 
    Sqrt[(b - 2 c - a c)^2 - (b^2 - c^2) (3 - 4 a - a^2 + b^2 - c^2) x + 
      (b^2 - c^2) x^2]] + 
  Sqrt[1 + a - (b - c) (c - b x - c x) + 
    Sqrt[(b - 2 c - a c)^2 - (b^2 - c^2) (3 - 4 a - a^2 + b^2 - c^2) x + 
      (b^2 - c^2) x^2]]

Reduce[
  0 <= (1/4) (1 - a - b - c) <= 1 &&
  0 <= (1/4) (1 + a + b - c) <= 1 &&
  0 <= (1/4) (1 + a - b + c) <= 1 &&
  0 <= (1/4) (1 - a + b + c) <= 1 &&
  a^2 < b^2 < c^2, 
  {a, b, c}, Reals];

NSolve[D[f[x], x] > 0]
```

I did try to do this im many ways. I'm pretty new to *Mathematica* and today I thought of doing it this way, but it's not working

Comment: 1. Post mathematica code for your function, not an image. 2. Show the code you have put together so far.

Comment: im pretty new so im just learning sory for all my bads is it properly posted now ?

Comment: Much better. Now consider that in *Mathematica* `bx` indicates a single variable called $bx$, **not** the product `b*x` as you wanted. To indicate the product, add a space in your code between $b$ and $x$: `b x`, or use an explicit multiplication sign (`*`). Also, you have some special character \[Minus] in your `Reduce` expression: replace it with a "normal" minus sign, i.e. a hyphen on the keyboard. When you make those changes, your `Reduce` expression will return a result. `Solve` or `NSolve`, however, will really struggle to solve your equation symbolically.

Comment: is there anyway i can  speed up  the proces? like stop using numerial methods or something ?

Comment: k_z numerical methods are actually almost invariably MUCH faster than symbolic computation. That's the problem here actually: you should look into numerical methods instead! But before you move any further, please attempt to clarify your question as much as you can.

Comment: I need to check when its increasing or decreasing and when (for example x^2 is decreasing from minus infinity to 0 and increasing from 0 to infiity).I need to do this for 0<=x<=1, but apparently this question is from qauntum informatics field so im not sure if there is sombody who can help me .

Comment: You still have basic error in code: `ac` should be `a c` in several places.

Comment: What does the `Reduce` expression have to do with the rest of the code? (Note that the trailing semicolon returns null output from the `Reduce` expression!)  Are the conditions there meant to represent constraints upon the parameters `a`, `b`, and `c`?

Comment: yes. this 5 ineqautions are coditions that are meant to represent it u are correct. as i told english is not my native and im new to mathematica and i did try to do "something" with reduce since all my previous attempts failed.

Comment: If ANYONE have idea how should i write the code and can explain my why it work this way I would be rly glad and in debt. Why for example FullSimplify[D[f[x], x]] is running forever and D[f[x],x] work rly fast.

Comment: The `FullSimplify` is trying to simplify your expression. It involves square roots of square roots, so you might guess it is not trivial to find simplifications. Moreover, you do not specify `Assumptions` on `a,b,c,x` so that Mathematica assumes they are complex - which in turn might prevent the simplification routines from finding solutions. `D[f[x],x` is just a straightforward derivative, without any further simplification applied - hence very fast.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Simplify](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html).

If $f(x)$ is a function, then

```
Simplify[f[x]>=f[y], x>=y]
```

should evaluate to the necessary condition for the monotonicity to hold. If necessary, you can use [FullSimplify](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html)

Comment: but true or false dont give me answer in which areas the function is increasing or decreasing? and i have to know that, thats why i thought i had to use
    D[f[x],x] and check when its + or -

Comment: @k_z, your function is monotonic if and only if it is either entirely increasing or decreasing; if there are areas in which it is increasing and also areas in which it is decreasing, then it is not monotonic.

Comment: ok english is not my native language i need to check in what parts is it increasing and decreasing. I'm pretty sure in a "usuall" math u have to calculate derivative and check if its bigger or smaller than "0"

Answer (score 1):

As an example, consider this function `g` and its derivative `gd`:

```
g[x_] := x - 1/10*x^3;
gd[x_] = D[g[x], x];
```

[image]

Now you want to study monotonicity in a certain interval. For this, you will need to find the local extrema of your function. The corresponding x-values of your extrema can be found using `Solve`, `NSolve` or `FindRoot` (for this simple example, `Solve` works - in general the other two approaches are required for numerical solutions).

```
xextreme = Solve[gd[x] == 0, x][[;; , 1, 2]]
{-Sqrt[(10/3)], Sqrt[10/3]}
```

Now you need to study the derivative's sign in the intervals separated by these values. To do so, we generate a list that has values "left" and "right" as well as in between the values found in `xextreme`. This is general, though very likely not the most beautiful approach (but the first that came to my mind and suffices).

```
testvals = Append[Prepend[(Drop[Riffle[#, # + 1/2*Append[Differences@#, 0]], -1] &@xextreme), -2*#], 2*#] &@Max[Abs[xextreme]]
{-2 Sqrt[10/3], -Sqrt[(10/3)], 0, Sqrt[10/3], 2 Sqrt[10/3]}
```

Now check the sign of the derivative:

```
TableForm[Transpose[{testvals, Sign[gd[#]] & /@ testvals}], TableHeadings -> {None, {"x", "sign(g'(x))"}}]
```

[image]

- Negative sign: decreasing function
- Positive sign: increasing function
- Zero: local extrema (including possibility of saddle point)

Note that if you use `NSolve` or `FindRoot`, you should rather use `Sign[Chop@gd[#]]` inside the `TableForm` line to get around numerical issues.

**Update**

To be very specific for your function in question: Have a look at [this beautiful package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103937/21606) and evaluate these lines

```
Needs["ConstantsGrouping`"];
ClearAll[fc,fcs, rule1,rule2];
{fc[x_], rule1} = GroupConstants[f[x], x, GeneratedParameters -> (Symbol["kf" <> ToString[#]] &)];
{fcs[x_], rule2} = GroupConstants[Numerator@Together@D[fc[x], x], x, GeneratedParameters -> (Symbol["kfs" <> ToString[#]] &)];
```

Then, observe the "beauty" of `fcs[x]`. All these hundreds of constants `kxyz` depend on `a,b,c` as specified in `rule1,rule2`. You may even do `fcs[x]/.rule2/.rule1` and see how large your expression becomes. Note that this is only the numerator of the derivative `f'[x]`. You would need to find roots of this thing, which appears to be impossible symbolically. Also, the numerical values will all (AFAIK) fail unless you specify values for `a,b,c`because there will be non-numerical values inside your expressions.

Comment: I got the method but I can not folow it. It works easy if try it for simple functions, but i can not apply it to the one im trying to solve. If anyone can tell me how can i do this step by step  it would be  great. My problem is I can not use FindRoot on my function and if i try something like   
    xextreme = NSolve[{fd[x] == 0,  0 <= (1/4)*(1 -a - b -c) <= 1, 
   0 <= (1/4) (1 + a + b- c) <= 1, 
   0 <= (1/4) (1 + a- b + c) <= 1, 
   0 <= (1/4) (1 - a + b + c) <= 1, a^2 < b^2 < c^2}, {x, a, b,
    c}, Reals] 
its not working

Comment: @k_z Please the my updated answer. I doubt you will find a solution of the problem as stated right now.

Comment: I installed the package. First i did try to this myself and i failed. I did try to copy what u worte and its not working properly either way I did something wrong or it do not work with this expression. This is what i got http://postimg.org/image/t5zftffu3/

Comment: @k_z Is the `GroupConstants` command written in blue colour?

Comment: Yes it is writen in blue colour

Comment: can u do this part and send me an .nb file so i can check what did i do wrong?

Comment: You have to copy the package source code into a new notebook, change the cell type to CODE and then save it as a package (ConstantsGrouping.m) into the folder which you get by evaluating `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`. You have not installed the package properly

Comment: So i did copy the code made new nb put in a new CODE type Cell and used File>install>pacage>From file . and its not working anyway ?

Comment: @k_z 1. Open new nb 2. Evaluate `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications` and copy the resulting path somewhere (or remember it, whatsoever) 3. delete ALL cells in this nb 4. Paste the package source code into the nb 5. Highlight the entire cell 6. Format->Style->Code 7. File->Save As (Select "Wolfram Mathematica Package") "ConstantsGrouping.m" into the folder from step 2. Then close all instances of Mathematica (maybe even restart your machine to be entirely sure). After that the package MUST be installed properly. Just proceed as was written...

Comment: I did 4 times and each time nothing changed all i get is this http://postimg.org/image/5aj8soewb/ i do everthing just the way u describe it and its just not working

Comment: @k_z Remove the semicolon after the `Needs` and see what it prints

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/z3zcu6x0r/

Comment: Hard to read, but I guess you did not save the `ConstantsGrouping` code into a SEPARATE file into `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications` as I told you. It looks like you have the package source code after the `Needs[...]` which does not make sense. Please carefully read the 7 steps above. Follow step by step and izt will work

Comment: I reinstalled the program and i got it right  i gues since the error since the error lines changed http://postimg.org/image/mcg329orv/

Comment: @k_z It is hard to say what goes wrong from a remote place if you are just guessing. Firstly, make sure the package is correctly installed. This, again, is explained in the 7 step comment of mine. Once you've done this, start a *fresh* Mathematica session and ONLY evaluate `Needs["ConstantsGrouping`"]` (note there is no semicolon). This will indicate if the package is installed properly. Right now it appears this is not the case. This is my last comment about that. Make sure to copy-paste everything between the `BeginPackage` and `EndPackage` lines in proper format...

Comment: ... there is a lot of mess going on with `RowBox`es and stuff in your screenshots. Debug step by step and install the package as described - then the rest of the code will show what it is supposed to.

Comment: So i try my best to do everthing step by step. So far i got this http://postimg.org/image/auu8c6lnv/