# Solving 4 coupled linear 1st order ODE with constant coefficients

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning

I'm getting trouble solving these 4 coupled differential equations, just can't get a result while it keep running.
[image]

```
eqs = 
{
A1'[t] ==  I (μ0 - 2*g) A1[t] - I g0 (B1[t] + C1[t]), 
B1'[t] == -I (g0 (2 + n) A1[t] + Ω C1[t] + g0 D1[t]), 
C1'[t] == -I (g0 (2 + n) A1[t] + Ω B1[t] + g0 D1[t]), 
D1'[t] == -I g0 (1 + n) (B1[t] + C1[t]) - I (μ0 - 2 g) D1[t], 
A1[0] == 0, B1[0] == 0, C1[0] == 0, D1[0] == 1
};
dusol = DSolve[eqs, {A1, B1, C1, D1}, t][[1]] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Don't use `\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(A1\), \('\)]\)[t]` to describe the derivative. Use `A1'[t]` instead.

Comment: Good question.  Something definitely is wrong!

Comment: Just to make sure, your _trouble_ is `DSolve` runs forever, right?

Comment: No, it reports error and can't run, let alone get a result.

Comment: @xzczd  The problem as stated runs forever for Version 12.1.1.  Eliminating both the initial conditions and `FullSimplify` yields an enormous answer after several minutes.  The matrix of the right sides of the equations is not Hermitian, but `Eigensystem` does produce results quickly.  However, `JordanDecomposition` crashes.  Possibly a bug.

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify the _trouble_ you have. In _v12.1.1_ the code just just runs forever. Which version are you in? BTW, you need to add @xzczd in your comment, or I won't get the reminder. (You may want to read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/284701) to learn the usage of @. )

Comment: @xzczd OK, I use the version 10.1. The error it outputs is "Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed."

Comment: …You got this warning with `\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(A1\), \('\)]\)[t]`, right? I guess you obtained this by stroking **Ctrl** + **6** first? Then you've typed `'` in wrong way. You should directly type `'` i.e. `A1'[t]` is the correct input. Now copy the code in your question back to _Mathematica_ and retry. (BTW, if you insist on stroking **Ctrl** + **6** first, then what you should type is `\[Prime]`. )

Comment: @xzczd Yes, you are absolutely right! Now it just keep running .

Comment: Problem with `JordanDecomposition` noted in earlier comment report to Wolfram, Inc as CASE:4633110.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found 3 work-arounds.

First one is to make use of the [`` ConstantsGrouping` ``  package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103937/14303):

```
head = {A1, B1, C1, D1};
var = Through@head@t;

{newrhs, rule} = GroupConstants[eqs[[;; 4, -1]], {t, var} // Flatten]

lhs = eqs[[;; 4, 1]]

solmid = DSolve[{lhs == newrhs // Thread, eqs[[5 ;;]]}, head, t]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {12.4674, Null} *)

sol = var /. solmid[[1]] /. rule;
```

Second one is based on `LaplaceTransform`:

```
teqs = LaplaceTransform[eqs[[;; 4]], t, s] /. Rule @@@ eqs[[5 ;;]]

tsol = Solve[teqs, LaplaceTransform[var, t, s]][[1, All, -1]]

sol2 = InverseLaplaceTransform[tsol, s, t]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.968162, Null} *)
```

Last, and the fastest one is to utilize `MatrixExp`:

```
{barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[eqs[[;; 4, -1]], var];

sol3 = MatrixExp[marray t, eqs[[5 ;;, -1]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.458083, Null} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solutions. They're very useful. I've solved my problem. And importantly, I left out the initial condition $μ0=2g,g0=g$!